# Performance optimization for Nested loop C# and Epplus (inserting data into rows)

Tags: c#, excel, nested-loops, epplus

I have a stock scanner project where I am working with an API to get data based on certain price parameters.

the data gets callbacked in several methods which I then am using with EPPlus to open and update my excel file.

the data comes back in the following order

1st loop (request stock symbols from API)
for each symbol we have another loop to get contract details from API, (2nd loop)

for each contract we request market data from API (3rd loop)

for each market data we store as variable (4th loop)
each method is a public virtual void method

for loop 2-4 we are opening and editing an excel file with epplus

```
using (var package = new ExcelPackage(pathtofile))
{
    // edit excel file with the data callback from API

    package.Save();
}
```

I thought instead of opening and saving the excel file in each method,

1. I could instead pass the variables to the last method in a array and then do it there.
2. I could use `LoadFromCollection` of Epplus instead of calling each cell, currently I am calling each cell like so

   worksheet.Cells[row, 1].Value = mycelldata; where row is sheet.Dimension.End.Row + 1
3. I could use sql database instead of using excel, (keep in mind I don't plan on having large databases (less then 50,000 entries)

has anyone had any experience on my 3 previous methods or would like to suggest something new to speed up performance?